# Change fs.protected_hardlinks on Ubuntu docker container

Tags: docker, ubuntu, sysctl

I'm very new to docker but I'm trying to change that setting and the usual ways aren't working.

The settings is fs.protected_hardlinks to 1

I've tried changing /etc/sysctl.d files as well as the /etc/sysctl.conf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright everyone, i just learned a SH*T load about docker I never wanted to know but long story short here is how I got greengrass working on a docker container.

first launch docker toolbox, once its up I used virtualbox manager to log in and the running instance called "default" is the instance of docker server.

Logged into that and ran these 4 commands (btw I haven't figured out how to persist this so when someone does feel free to add that as a comment)

```
sudo su
echo "fs.protected_hardlinks = 1" >> /etc/sysctl.conf
echo "fs.protected_symlinks = 1" >> /etc/sysctl.conf
sysctl --system
```

Answer (score 0):

sysctl settings are usually system-wide and Docker containers are generally prohibited from changing them.  Change settings like this (that affect how the filesystem layer as a whole works, for all processes, in all containers) outside of Docker.

Comment: Ah thanks! Could you point me in the right direction where that specific setting can be changed? I'm on Windows using docker toolbox